# In pandas, how is it possible for a Boolean series of len(100) to be applied to a dataframe of len(10) without it throwing an error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, series

Apologies for not being able to provide the data. Somebody else wrote this code, and I don't understand how it's working.

There's a dataframe (`df`) that's say, 100 samples long. They grouped it:

[EDIT TO QUESTION: I forgot to include that the groupby statement ended with an index reset. Adding that below.]

`grouped_df = df.groupby('col_a').sum()['col_b'].sort_values().reset_index()`

This resulted in a DataFrame object of length 10.

Then they created a Boolean series to use as a mask. They created it from the original dataframe (`df`) based on values in a third column:

`mask = df['col_c'] > 10`

This resulted in a Boolean series of length 100—same length as `df`, naturally.

Then they applied `mask` (len=100) to `grouped_df` (len=10), and the result was a DataFrame object of length 5.

How does that work? What is happening? How can you apply a Boolean series to a dataframe as a mask when the lengths don't match up?

Comment: It should raise an 'Item wrong length' error. Print the mask - there must be something you are missing

Comment: try to print the shape of your data structures using df.shape, maybe it's applying on some dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is my [*previous*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76493428/1) answer to the original [*question*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76493288/1).

***Update :***

That's because pandas silently aligns the indexes of the `grouped_df` with the boolean `mask`.

Here is a configuration that would lead to a similar scenario :

```
np.random.seed(20)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col_a": np.random.choice(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), 100),
    "col_b": np.random.randint(0, 20, 100),
    "col_c": np.random.randint(0, 30, 100)
})

grouped_df = (
    df.groupby("col_a").sum()["col_b"]
    .sort_values().reset_index() # length of 10
)

mask = df["col_c"] > 10 # length of 100

out = grouped_df[mask] # length of 5
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  col_a  col_b
1     H     52
2     C     70
3     I     70
6     F     87
9     G    190
```

*Intermediates/Details :*

```
#A friendly warning
UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
 
>>> grouped_df
  col_a  col_b
0     B     41
1     H     52
2     C     70
3     I     70
4     D     76
5     E     86
6     F     87
7     A    107
8     J    116
9     G    190

>>> grouped_df.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1)

>>> mask[mask.eq(True)].index
Index([ 1,  2,  3,  6,  9, 10, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
       29, 30, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 43, 44, 45, 49, 50, 51, 53, 54,
       61, 63, 64, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 74, 75, 78, 79, 81, 83, 84, 85, 88, 89,
       90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96, 97],
      dtype='int64')

>>> grouped_df.index.intersection(mask[mask.eq(True)].index)
Index([1, 2, 3, 6, 9], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: This is fascinating, and I'm trying to wrap my head around it. Thank you! A few notes. `grouped_df` is indeed a DataFrame object when I check it. It's not a Series. Also, `col_a` holds strings (countries). I'm grouping by country. Also, sorry, I accidentally omitted a bit of the groupby() statement. They ended it by resetting the index. I'll edit the question to indicate this.

Comment: No worries, I updated my answer accordingly ;)

Comment: Ok, I see exactly what's happening now. This person's code is actually problematic. It's just taking all the indexes of `df` that are `True` based on the condition set forth in `mask` up to index `len(df_grouped`), which in the case of my example arbitrarily ends up being 5 rows. This is meaningless in the context of the problem I'm working on, and it's not what the author of the code thinks their code is doing. Thanks again for your help, @Timeless. This was illuminating.